# UITableView with multiple sections and custom section header with single cell selection and multiple cell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I am setting `UITableView` with multiple sections and section one has a single selection and section two multiple selections it wants exactly what is happening in `UberEats` when choosing add-ons and type of food

I have made expanding and closing of cell rows and I want to update labels in a custom header

`var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?`

In `cellForRowAt`

```
if let inxPath = selectedIndexPath{
            if inxPath.section == 0{
                if inxPath == indexPath{
                    if inxPath.row == indexPath.row && inxPath.section == indexPath.section{
                        cell.radioButtonImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "radioCheck")
                    }
                }
            }
            if inxPath.section == 1{
                if inxPath.row == indexPath.row && inxPath.section == indexPath.section{
                    if cell.radioButtonImageView.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconUnmarked"){
                        cell.radioButtonImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconMarked")
                    }else if cell.radioButtonImageView.image == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconMarked"){
                        cell.radioButtonImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconUnmarked")
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

In `didSelectRowAt`

```
selectedIndexPath = indexPath
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an int and array of of int instance properties to store selected row details.

```
var selectedOfferIndex: Int? // section 0
var selectedItemIndices: [Int] = []//section 1
```

In cellForRowAt compare the selected values and change UI

```
if section == 0 {
    if indexPath.row == selectedOfferIndex {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
} else {//section 1
    if selectedItemIndices.contains(indexPath.item) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

In didSelectRowAt method update the selected values

```
if section == 0 {
    selectedOfferIndex = indexPath.row
} else {//section 1
    if index = selectedItemIndices.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
        selectedItemIndices.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        selectedItemIndices.append(indexPath.row)
    }
}
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: thanx bro for help but in multiple selections I am unable to deselect a row

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper Select the same cell it will be deselected

Comment: if I select all rows then no row can be deselected can it  work like multiple selections and no selection

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper If you select a cell twice what happens?

Comment: how can I get more help from you I am stuck in code

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper what is the problem?